# Meaning of "magari"

Tags: meaning

My dictionary translates 'magari' as 'maybe'. However, I know that it can be used as interjection to mean something like "I wish!". My question is, when it's used in a sentence like this:

> Magari ci vediamo stasera

Is does this mean "maybe we'll see each other tonight" or does it mean "hopefully we'll see each other tonight"? Or is it somewhere *between* 'maybe' and 'hopefully'?

Comment: Magari - "if only it could be".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means *I wish* when it is used as exclamation.

> **A**: Vuoi che ti accompagni?
>   **B**: Magari!

It has that meaning in a sentence using the subjunctive mood too.

> Magari potessi venire anche io al concerto!

> Magari fosse vero che sono fidanzato con Veronica!

> Magari non fosse venuta alla festa! Mi ha fatto litigare con la mia ragazza, che se ne è andata prima che potessi darle il regalo.

When used with the Simple Present and the Simple Past, it normally means *maybe*, *possibly*.

> Magari non sapeva niente.

> Magari non è stato avvisato in tempo.

> Magari è solo in ritardo.

Notice that you could read *Magari non c'ero!* instead of *Magari non ci fossi stato*, but in both the cases it  means "I wish I was not there." As in English, the subjunctive mood is often replaced from the indicative mood, at least colloquially.
In that case, the difference is made from the intonation.

Comment: I changed your ‘eventually’ into ‘possibly’; watch out for false friends! `;-)`

Comment: I am sorry I didn't approve your suggestion; I keep forgetting we still don't have the privilege of editing every post, and I thought you edited it when you wrote the comment, while you suggested an edit.

Comment: *"Magari non c'ero!" sounds to me as simply wrong --- I am Italian (La Spezia), and maybe could be used somewhere else, but I would plainly not understand it.

Comment: I've never heard *Magari non c'ero* in my life and it sounds as absolutely wrong, unless you mean *maybe I wasn't even there* after someone yelled at you for doing something taking as a given that you were there, when you in fact weren't.

Comment: Would you translate it in some cases as "hopefully" (like ojalá in spanish http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/ojal%C3%A1), and when?

Comment: @bbozo No. It is more "I wish" than "I hope."

Answer (score 9):

Wow, what an overloaded word! It has **six** different meanings or usages I can find.

As an adverb it may mean *maybe* (*cf. “forse”*)

> A: Ci vediamo?
>
> B: Magari sì.

but it can also mean *even* (*cf. “persino”*)

> A: Ci vediamo?
>
> B: Vengo assolutamente, magari a piedi!

As a conjunction it can similarly mean *even if* (*cf. “persino se”*)

> Lo aspetterò, magari dovessi restare qui tutta la notte.

or, *if only* (*cf. “se solamente”*)

> Eravamo soli, magari fossi venuto!

As an interjection it can either mean *I can only wish…*, but also *I really want to!* depending on context and/or emphasis.

The word comes from the  Greek μακάρι (makári), which is derived from μακάριος (makários), according to [etimo.it](http://www.etimo.it/?term=magari) and it can be loosely translated as *“God(s) willing!”*

#### References

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/magari
- http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/magari.shtml
- http://it.thefreedictionary.com/magari
- http://www.etimo.it/?term=magari

Answer (score 6):

It can mean both as you correctly say and it is open to interpretation, it's hard to answer your question out of a specific context. This phenomenon happens in other languages as well. Just know that it does have a double meaning and try to understand what's being said given your specific context.